# Como hacer que un Nodo2D siga al cursor sin Retraso

Tags: c++, nativescript

Estoy programando un juego en Godot utilizando C++, tengo un objeto Nodo2D que sigue al cursor

```
void Personaje::_process(float delta) {
   // Obtenemos la posicion del cursor //
   GetCursorPos(&cursorus);
   // Establecemos la posición del personaje // 
   set_position(Vector2((float)cursorx.x, 0));
}
```

Lo que ocurre es que el personaje que es un Nodo2D sigue al cursor pero tiene un Retraso (Delay) es decir que el personaje no se mueve al mismo tiempo que el cursor por lo que tarda unas décimas de segundo en igualar su posición.

Existirá algún método para hacer que un Nodo2D se mueva exactamente con el cursor?

O algún método para que el Nodo2D sea controlado por la entrada del mouse?

Comment: Tal vez tengas que aumentar las veces que se refresca la pantalla(fps) para una mayor precisión.

Comment: Realmente no hay una solución como tal, es decir no importa si es UNITY, GODOT, GAMEMAKER cuando un objecto cual sea sigue el cursor siempre tendra un pequeño delay.
Pero pues es algo con lo que se tiene que vivir.

La unica alternativa que encontre es hacer que el personaje sea el Puntero. Pero aun asi, requeriria pasar mas parametros como la Shape collision etc etc.